# search for string with underscore

Tags: java

Can I use the equals operator to match a **case-sensitive** `String` that contains underscore?

```
str1.trim() == "Aavik_aArjun"
```

Or should I use a regex for this simple match as the equals operator is not working?

Comment: You should always compare strings with `equals()` method not with `==`.

Comment: equal isn't an operator. equals is a method. if it doesn't return true, than the two Strings aren't equal. it 's that simple

Comment: @Stultuske '==' is an operator and the answer is, that it can't be used for Strings...

Comment: @Turo yes, '==' is an operator, but I wasn't talking about that. secondly, it can be used for Strings, it can be used for any type, but it won't always give you the result you expect.

Comment: @Stultuske: Touché :-)

Comment: @Turo had the OP mentioned the equality (instead of equal) operator, I would have assumed he was talking about == :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `String` (and objects in general) use the **.equals()** method and not the `==` operator, as the former compares the references and not the actual content of the Strings.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @MCEmperor possibly, it does. With a bit imagination, you can read the OP's question as: myString == "value" doesn't work. How come?

Comment: @Stultuske Well, in that case it should be marked as duplicate of [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) Also, OP seems to be mixing checking strings for equality and checking whether a *substring* occurs (the word "contains" implies that). Imagination is a little subjective.